# SOQL query error on CPU TImeout for Batch Apex

Tags: soql, batch, cpulimit

I have a Batch Apex operation that is part of a managed package that is failing in the start() method or soon after since the start() log is the last one displayed.  I run a SOQL query that gets all fields (essentially SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Id != null) for all Account objects as well as two subquery aggregations on Contacts and Opportunities for the Account (but with LIMIT of 10 each).

When building the query, I get all fields on an Account using something like this..(it works) `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap`

It runs with no problem (ie within 1800 ms on 1000 records) in my organization's production org.  But when I move to a customer's org, it slows considerably (ie 90,000 to 120,000 ms on 5000 records) and causes a CPU timeout error.  What could cause such a difference in performance from my org to a customer's org?  Any suggestions?  I could cut some of the fields out since I do not need all fields but every customer's field set is different so I need the dynamic build on the fields used in the query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apex CPU Time limit in Batch start() - is this a Query Timeout and how to cope with?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44379/apex-cpu-time-limit-in-batch-start-is-this-a-query-timeout-and-how-to-cope-w)

Comment: It was the subquerries that slowed the operation down substantially.  After removing them, the SOQL operation went from 90-120 sec to 900 ms.